# UNIX Operating Structure layer functionality

Tags: unix

[Unix Operating System Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F0xD.jpg)

The picture provided is a sketh of a Unix operating system.

I'm not sure how the Unix OS works and these are some questions I had about it.

What is the overall functionalitiy of each of the layers labeled by numbers and the interfaces between the adjacent layers?

What is the purpose of organizing the components like this?

How would each of these layers differ from the OS of an android or IOS (mobile OS)

Thanks!

Comment: These are waaayyy too broad questions for this very narrowly focused Q&A site I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Userspace

The two top layer (the one called "the users"), plus the one labeled (1), are the **userspace**.
A UNIX process can't exist outside userspace.

Layer (1) is sometimes refered as "shell" layer.
It's not always clear what is or is not is shell layer. For short, we can consider this as the "system" part of userspace (by opposition to end-user applications). Typically, think of the command line utilities like cp, rm, mv, ln, ls, etc.

userspace provides memory isolation between process (one process can't write unexpectedly in other processes memory space).

Also, a program in userspace runs under a user identity, which provides him permissions to manipulate some resources in the system. An exemple is : you have a file that you owns in your home directory, which permission are -r-------- (readonly, only for the owner).
No other (unpriviledged) user in the system will be able to display its content, since any command they run inherit their identity and permissions.

## Kernel

The layer 2 is the **kernel**. It is a very priviledged piece of code that is responsible to provide the features needed to acheive the userspace.

It is also the first piece of the system that is loaded into memory and then executed at boot time (just after the firmware bootloader).

It initialise the CPU and motherboard devices, and notably sets up the Memory Management Unit of modern processor. Momery isolation of processes relies on MMU operation mode.

The kernel is responsible to manage resources allocation (memory, files on hard disk, etc). Also responsible to kill a process that makes illegal accesses (for instance, outside its allocated memory space).

## Why two layer ?

Beyond the technical justification presented above, there is another strong reason to have make this choice.

This layer concept comes from the early UNIX systems, and it is a core concept of all modern OSes (NB : the term Operating System, sometimes refers to the kernel only).
Indeed, by the time, they was no way to port a software to another computer model, furthermore if not designed by the same manufacturer.

The kernel was introduced to ease the port of software : when receiving a new computer model, Bell Labs had to make the effort to port the kernel, and the C compiler to this new machine, maybe some tweaks in system libraries.
But when this port was acheived, all other userspace software could be recompiled and executed on the new machine.

Also, it allows a same C code to be used (theorically) on different kernel implementation. 
For instance, many of the tools you can find under linux are also usable under FreeBSD.
I don't mean a clone of the tools, i mean the same source code, compiled for the right target system.

Those comment are cleary not exhaustive, it's a hugely vast topic, but I hope it helps for pathfinding :)

Concrete instance :

- basically GNU is a collection of system tools (a shell)
- in a GNU/ Linux system GNU runs on a Linux kernel

NB : paradoxally, GNU is older than Linux

**EDIT**

I don't know for iOS but android is, basically a Linux system.
So it implements this layer concept, with a kernel and a userspace.

Anyway, despite it is based on Linux kernel, not on "vanilla" version, but a version highly tweaked by google developers.
The shell is also highly specific for the base distribution form google (AOSP) but theorically, GNU tools can be installed.

Comment: @Pekka : anyway I had few dozen of minutes to kill on this hugelyyyy vast topic it seems ;°)

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions which are off-topic according to the guidelines in the [help]. Thanks.